# Determine the operating system

Tags: paths

I often switch between Linux and Windows. A number of my LaTeX files use images from a central folder. All of these are within a Dropbox folder, which is how I sync between them.

The dropbox folders are in different paths on Windows and Linux, so I would like to make a macro which detects the OS and uses the correct path.

Comment: How do you transfer the .tex between the linux and windows machine? If you put it in the dropbox folder as well, you can use relative paths.

Comment: Check the `ifplatform` package.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

write into your document

```
\graphicspath{{c:/Windows/images/User/}{/home/me/images/}}
```

and then use only the filename of the image. You have to use slashes for directories in Linux *and* Windows.

Answer (score 20):

There should be no need to put any tests in your documents, just use

```
\includegraphics{file}
```

and arrange that your dropbox folder is in your TEXINPUTS environment variable or (better) texmf.cnf setting on your two machines and it should all just work.

Answer (score 6):

For windows refugees, remember that Windows  also has symlinks (use mklink or from right click window->new create shortcut).

```
 \graphicspath{{../Dropbox/pic/}{{/home/me/images/}}}
```

where, `Dropbox` is the `shortcut` name to the Dropbox `shortcut`.

The advantage of this, is that I wouldn't have the `LaTeX` file in the dropbox folder (all sorts of problems). Rather place your `LaTeX` file somewhere separate say your Github folder.

My suggestion also is that is always better to use a version control system and only use Dropbox for back-ups.

Comment: dropbox is a file syncing solution. Use a real backup solution for backups!