# How can I easily use the same preamble on all my documents?

Tags: input, include, paths, preamble

I use multiple computers (Mac and PC), so creating a path (e.g. `\input{c:/folder/Preamble}`) won't work.  I really want to assign a URL (in Dropbox) to the file and input the file via the URL, but I don't know what command to use to achieve that.  Suggestions?

Comment: Something along http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/99090/determine-the-operating-system/99104#99104 ?

Comment: See package `ifplatform`.

Answer (score 16):

This is what has been working great for me for about two years now.

- create a .sty file containing your universal preamble. A .sty file, basically, is a regular TeX file starting with `\ProvidesPackage{mystyle}`, ending with `\endinput`, and everything else inbetween.*)
- in your Dropbox (or similar), create a directory named `texmf-local`, and a subdirectory such as `mypackages`, and put your .sty file there. [it might be a good idea to follow the standard TeX Directory Structure, and make `mypackages` a subdirectory of `temxmf-local/tex/latex/`]
- add that new `texmf-local` to the list of paths scanned by `texhash`. In my case (as a TeXLive user), this means modifying  `texmf.cnf`:
  `TEXMFLOCAL = $SELFAUTOPARENT/../texmf-local;e:/files/dropbox/texmf-local`.
- run a `texhash` and `kpsewhich mystyle.sty` to confirm everything's okay.
- in your documents, load your preamble via `\usepackage{mystyle}`. No additional packages are needed for all this to work. Plus, it's completely platform-agnostic.

needless to say, step 3 (and 4) has to be done separately on each machine.

Over time, in my case, this has developed from a mere universal preamble into a full-fledged package with lots of options, internal sub-routines and dependencies. There's a lot of things you can do with a .sty file you can't do with a simple `\input...`

*) Consult `clsguide.pdf` for details about package writing.

Comment: I would suggest that the local texmf directory follow the [TeX Directory Structure](http://tug.org/twg/tds/), so a custom package would go in `temxmf-local/tex/latex/mypackages/`  At the same time you can put your images in `texmf-local/tex/generic/images`, etc.

Comment: yes, that's certainly the more standard way. Added it to my post.

Comment: I was curious about the advantages of doing it with a package. I asked a question about it here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/139157/what-are-the-pros-and-cons-of-packages-versus-input-for-a-preamble

Answer (score 6):

Here's what I ended up doing:

```
\usepackage{ifplatform, pdftexcmds, catchfile}

\ifwindows

\input{% windows path to preamble}

\fi

\ifmacosx

\input{% mac path to preamble}

\fi
```