# What are the pros and cons of packages versus \input for a preamble?

Tags: input, package-writing, preamble

For a some simple cases it seems to me that there would be no important difference between

1. putting some code in a file `preamble.tex` and having `\input{preamble.tex}` in the main .tex file
2. putting it in a file `preamble.sty` (with appropriate modifications such as a `\ProvidesPackage`)

What are the pros and cons of each?

Comment: The biggest “contra” for this approach is that one tends to accumulate scores of packages that probably are not needed in a document.

Comment: That's true, but wouldn't it apply to both 1. and 2.?

Comment: Related/Duplicate: [Should I make a package or class for my usual preamble, or include it in every document?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/116275/15717)

Comment: I'd say that any differences between the two approaches must surely range between trivial and insignificant. E.g., having to remember to use `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` to surround instructions that contain the character `@` in the method based on `\input preamble` is one such difference that hopefully nobody will consider to be major. Far more important would have to be the decisions as to real stuff that should be in the file preamble.tex/preamble.sty.

Comment: @texenthusiast The answer you suggest is related, and helpful, but not a duplicate because I'm not comparing the package approach to having the code in the main file.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The differences are:

1. You cannot pass package options in  `usepackage[<options>]{preamble}` when using `input{preamble}` as `\input` has no optional arguments.
2. For cases in which you need `@` as a character in your macros, for example, you don't need `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` when implementing package. But you really need `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` when implementing with `\input`.
3. Still searching...

Comment: Still searching... :)