# What is the difference between putting macros in a .sty package file vs. simply \input them from another .tex file?

Tags: packages, input

If `\input` just ["imports the commands from the [target file]"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/250/17835) into your new document, then what is the difference between calling a set of commands via `\input{filename}` (where `filename` is some `.tex` document) and creating a package with these commands defined and calling that package via `\usepackage`?

Comment: `\makeatletter ... \makeatother` is not needed when implementing packages with macros using @ as parts of their names.

Comment: If I understand correctly (which I may not), `\usepackage{foo}` will only load `foo` the first time it is called. This is especially useful for packages that load other packages, to avoid redundancies and conflicts that come from importing the same code more than once.

Comment: @texenthusiast It seems like my question is a proper part of [What are the pros and cons of package versus \input for a preamble?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/139157/what-are-the-pros-and-cons-of-packages-versus-input-for-a-preamble) so this is more or less a duplicate. Vote issued to close.